# what is meaning of "unite by lack of"?

Tags: meaning

> This vision of human possibility led him to a range of subjects **united
>   mainly by their total lack of intellectual respectabilty**: murder, the
>   occult, sexuality. (*[At the Existentialist Café](https://books.google.com/books?id=nKnSCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA290&lpg=PA290&dq=This%20vision%20of%20human%20possibility%20led%20him%20to%20a%20range%20of%20subjects%20united%20mainly%20by%20their%20total%20lack%20of%20intellectual%20respectabilty:%20murder,%20the%20occult,%20sexuality.&source=bl&ots=YW9L55tLlY&sig=bRV9YZLr4thyV4d3YGx6PXUgRN4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis9Jm98sbOAhVYz2MKHY51DaYQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=This%20vision%20of%20human%20possibility%20led%20him%20to%20a%20range%20of%20subjects%20united%20mainly%20by%20their%20total%20lack%20of%20intellectual%20respectabilty%3A%20murder%2C%20the%20occult%2C%20sexuality.&f=false),* by Sarah
>   Bakewell)

Does "their" refer to subjects? Could you please rewrite the sentence?

Comment: What does your dictionary have for _united by X_?

Answer (score 2):

"This vision of human possibility led him to a range of subjects - murder, the occult, sexuality - that had only one thing in common:  a total lack of intellectual respectability."

You were correct:  The word **their** does refer to **subjects**.